# Не получается создать React Context при TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook, context

Объявляю контекст:

```
export const Context = React.createContext({})
```

Внук компонента выглядит так:

```
const { deleteRow } = useContext(Context)
```

В deleteRow возникает ошибка:

> TS2339: Property 'deleteRow' does not exist on type '{}'.

Пробую починить с помощью интерфейса в контексте:

```
interface IContext {
    list: []
    deleteRow(content: IItem): void
}

export const AnimalContext = React.createContext<IContext>({})
```

Первая ошибка исчезает, но появляется другая ошибка:

> TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IContext'.

Естественно, это плохой вариант - создавать внутри значения по умолчанию объект по типу IContext, да и доступа к ним снаружи компонента всё равно нет.

Как это починить?

Comment: попробуйте так `React.createContext({} as IContext)`